# SSIS condtional split to skip rows in a datetime column which has numbers

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, split, conditional-statements

I have a flat file source which is reading a .csv file. This file has a datetime column in which some rows have numbers. I want use a conditional split component to skip the rows which are having numbers in the datetime column when reading the file.

> ID Date PhoneNumber Query
>     1  05/01/2013 15:40 9879879877 Sometext
>     2  05/12/2013 8:30 9879879877 Sometext
>     3  2

The csv file is in the above format. Whenever the Date column has a number, PhoneNumber and Query columns are blank and i tried to use the following condition in conditional split to skip the 3rd row

> PhoneNumber!=""

The above condition in the conditional split is giving me the following error:

> The expression "PhoneNumber != """ on "output "PhoneNumber" (282)" evaluated to NULL, but the "component "PhoneNumber Check" (262)" requires a Boolean results. Modify the error row disposition on the output to treat this result as False (Ignore Failure) or to redirect this row to the error output (Redirect Row).  The expression results must be Boolean for a Conditional Split.  A NULL expression result is an error.

when i use the same condition with Query column it is skipping all the rows

so how can I skip the rows which are having numbers in a date time column using conditional split?

EDIT:

The files which I am trying to upload are in the following format

> ID Date PhoneNumber Query
>     1  05/01/2013 15:40 9879879877 Sometext
>     2  05/12/2013 8:30 9879879877 Sometext
>     3  2
>     4  05/12/2013 8:30 9879879877 Sometext
>     5  05/12/2013 8:30 9879879877 Sometext
>     6  05/12/2013 8:30 9879879877 Sometext
>     7  3
>     8  05/12/2013 8:30 9879879877 Sometext
>     9  05/12/2013 8:30 9879879877 Sometext

in every file there are about 3-4 faulty rows which needs to skipped but for some reason in the above example format the row with `ID 3` is getting skipped and row with `ID 7` is getting read as `3" "8` (it is some how mixing up or combining the numeric value in the `Date` column of row with `ID 7` with the entire next row, row with `ID 8`) and all the columns of row with `ID 8` are read with row with `ID 7` in a single row and all the blank columns of row with `ID 7` are skipped. I have already opened the file in notepad and checked the number of comma for that particular row and they are correct. Is the file faulty or something wrong in the package itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check for Null condition too

```
ISNULL([PhoneNumber]) || [PhoneNumber] != ""
```

or

```
ISNULL([PhoneNumber]) || LEN[PhoneNumber] != 0
```

Its working for me

Sample Date :-

[image]

I haven't selected the option `retain NULL value from the Source` option in Flat File Source component

Conditional Spilt Expression

[image]

Result :

[image]

The 3rd row is discarded in the above image.

BTW if you simple want to ignore the row containing invalid DateTime values then follow the below suggestion

If you simply want to validate the date column there are 3 ways of doing it :-

1.Change the column type to `Datetime` instead of `string` in Flat File Source and `redirect` the error rows to some file or table.

2.Use a `derived transformation` and cast the column to `DT_DBTIMESTAMP` and again redirect the error rows .

3.Use a `script` component and write a C# or Vb code to parse the [date] column like

```
row.ValidDate = DateTime.Parse(row.Date);
```

Create an output column `ValidDate` in `Script component`

Comment: i have tried both the conditions and for some reason it is skipping all the rows from the source file and nothing is getting added in the data base table. Why is this happening?

Comment: your conditions are working perfectly but i am facing a different problem now, edited the main question please check once

Comment: Can u show the original file with `column` and `row seperator`

Comment: the row separator i am using is `{LF}`, column separator is `, (comma)'` , header row separator is `{LF}` and text qualifier is `"` but how should i show you the original file? i am not allowed to share it..also if I change the file data and share it it may work but the original file may not work

Comment: The reason is because your Flat file is not properly `formated` .and SSIS is pretty poor in parsing flat files .Since you don't have 2 extra commas for the ID `3` and `7` .hence it merges these rows with the immediate one . You can however use C# or VB code to parse these file to check for rows which are not properly formated and add subsequent commas to differentiate the columns or use some [3rd tools](http://ssisdfs.codeplex.com/)